# Remove OnScrollChangeListener from NestedScrollView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, onscrolllistener

I have a `NestedScrollView` that I'm observing its scroll events using the following:

```
val scrollListener = NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
    Log.d(TAG, "scrollListener: Scrolled! $scrollY")
    setNavBarVisibilityFor(offset = scrollY)
}
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(scrollListener)
```

However, depending on an asynchronous event, I may, or may not, need to call another method in that scroll listener. In 80% of the cases I won't be needing the extra call, so I don't want to add a bool to check every time the scroll listener gets fired, and decide on the method call based on that.

I'm trying to remove the attached scroll listener from my `NestedScrollView` and create and attach a new one:

```
val extraScrollListener = NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
    Log.d(TAG, "extraScrollListener: Scrolled! $scrollY")
    setNavBarVisibilityFor(offset = scrollY)
    anotherMethodThatNeedsToBeRun(offset = scrollY)
}
//TODO: Remove the original scrollListener from the scrollView
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(extraScrollListener)
```

How can I remove the original `NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener` from my scrollView before attaching the new one?

Comment: Did you try setting `null` to get rid of the OnScrollChangeListener? This works with several other listeners which are assigned by "set...."

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Turns out that even calling `scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(extraScrollListener)
` will replace the old scroll listener with the new one, or the `null` that @BömachtBlau suggested. I may have been too tired yesterday and didn't realize where my Log statements were coming from.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, you will get ambiguity error. So, in that case you need to use this line of code:

```
mScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(null as NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener?)
```